# necesito recorrer linea a linea un fichero python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2.x

hola he estado desarrollando un programa en python para la empresa donde trabajo y el mismo toma unas direcciones ip desde un archivo **listaip.txt** para aplicar los comandos desde **comandos.txt**

actualmente el funciona a la perfección guardándome todos los resultados en un solo fichero **objetivo.txt** y mi jefe quiere que si tengo cinco direcciones genere cinco archivos diferentes con la informacion de cada uno, es decir, que el programa discrimine la cantidad de direcciones cuyo resultado se guarde en archivos separados.

```
def comandos():
try:
    #solicitamos los datos al usuario
    usuario=tkSimpleDialog.askstring("USUARIO", "Coloque el usuario:")
    clave=tkSimpleDialog.askstring("CONTRASENA", "Coloque la contrasena AAA:", show="*")

    #leemos el archivo listaip.txt y comandos.txt
    #en comandos.txt escribimos los comandos a enviar a los equipos remotos
    archivo1 = open("listaip.txt","r")
    archivo2 = open("comandos.txt","r")
    archivo3 = open("objetivo.txt","w")
    #guardamos en un archivo los resultados obtenidos al final del recorrido
    #leemos lo que contiene los archivos e igualamos a las variables del bucle
    terminales = archivo1.readlines()
    comandoss = archivo2.readlines()
    #bucle que recorre de acuerdo a las n cantidas de direcciones ip activas
    for host in terminales:
        #rstrip eliminamos los espacios que pudieren quedar antes o despues del salto de linea
        host = host.rstrip()
        for command in comandoss:
            #bucle que funciona de acuerdo a la cantidad de direcciones ip almacenadas en el archivo listaip.txt
            command = command.rstrip()
            name = socket.getfqdn()
            #eliminamos los espacios vacios
            #inicializamos el cliente ssh
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            #leemos la clave local
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            #efectuamos la conexion
            ssh.connect(host, username=usuario, password=clave)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
            #leemos la salida
            salida = stdout.read()
            #creamos una lista vacia
            lista =[]
            #anadimos los elementos de la salida al final de la lista
            lista.append(salida)
            #esto es para verificar en consola que si esta ejecutandose correctamente
            print "ok"
            #escribimos en el archivo
            archivo3.write(str((host + ":" + salida +" establecido con exito" + "\n" )))
            ssh.close()
            #cerramos la conexion y todos los archivos
    archivo1.close()
    archivo2.close()
    archivo3.close()
except:
    error1 = "\nError al ejecutar la conexion!\n"
    #tkMessageBox.showinfo("Resultado", error1)
```

Comment: No entiendo la relación entre lo que preguntas y el título de la pregunta. ¿Recorrer línea a línea un fichero? Eso aparentemente ya lo estás haciendo en tu código, no? Parece que lo que ahora necesitas es crear un fichero separado para cada línea del fichero "lsitaip.txt", si no entendí mal. ¿No es eso simplemente abrir `archivo3` dentro del bucle `for host in terminales`(y cerrarlo antes de la siguiente iteración) en vez de hacerlo antes? Naturalmente en cada iteración lo abrirás con un nombre diferente, que puedes crear a partir del valor de `host`.

Comment: si, entendiste muy bien pero como sugieres no hace más que con una dirección de la lista, intentando colocar `archivo3` dentro de cada uno de los bucles(jugando con los diferentes modo de apertura y cierre del archivo) no funciona

Comment: Por favor coloca solo la parte del código mínima necesaria para reducir tu problema, no necesitamos todo el programa.

Comment: editado para su fácil apreciación, nota el método de entrada es a través de una interfaz gráfica

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo te indicaba en el comentario es que la apertura del fichero en el que vas a escribir el resultado la hagas dentro del bucle `for`, abriendo un fichero diferente cada vez.

Es decir, algo como lo siguiente (he eliminado partes del código para dejar sólo lo relevante):

```
def comandos():
    # Omito el inicio que quedaría igual

    archivo1 = open("listaip.txt","r")
    archivo2 = open("comandos.txt","r")
    terminales = archivo1.readlines()
    comandoss = archivo2.readlines()

    # Ya que no vuelves a leer de archivo1 ni archivo2 podemos
    # cerrarlos ya aqui
    archivo1.close()
    archivo2.close()

    for host in terminales:
        host = host.rstrip()
        # El archivo3 se abre aquí, y su nombre es el del host, con extensión txt
        archivo3 = open("{}.txt".format(host), "w")
        for command in comandoss:
            # El interior de este bucle queda exactamente como estaba
        # Al salir de ese bucle, cerramos archivo3
        archivo3.close()
```

Comment: disculpa, intentando tus consejos sigue almacenando los resultados en el mismo archivo y no genera otros más (dependiendo de las veces que se repita el bucle...)

Comment: Si el nombre del host es el mismo de la forma que lo hace, escribirá siempre en el mismo documento, aunque sean dos elementos diferentes de la lista